# how to display only the current directory and git branch ?

Tags: iterm

my iterm path looks like the below, I saw the stack overflow post referencing http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528 which didn't work.  How to go about getting the file path reduced in size so that I can have a much smaller footprint?

ie, only have the current working directory and the git branch would be very useful.  thanks.

[jd@mbp ~/rubyonrailstutor/curriculum_apps/restaurantly (master)]$

Answer (score 0):

export PS1='[\u@mbp \W$(__git_ps1)]\$ '

Answer (score 0):

For those that are stumbling on this post years later like me. :-) Here is my setup to show only the current directory and current git branch in my terminal.

```
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="{ \[\033[36m\]\u \[\033[1;31m\]@\h \[\033[00m\]} \[\033[1;37m\]\W\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch) \[\033[34m\]$ \[\033[00m\]"
```

This gives you the following: [Terminal Output: Directory & Current Branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr29Q.png)

Any chunk that you see like this `[\033[36m\]` in the `export` line is doing the coloring of the text. You can do a search to see what values are available.

And that's it, short, sweet and colorified. :-)